# Bypass Foreign Key during data insertion

Tags: sql, django, postgresql, foreign-keys, rdbms

I have a function in my **views.py** which inserts data into **Table1** but one of the fields in **Table1** is a Foreign Key to the primary key of another table known as **Table2**.

**Note**:- Table2 is empty as of now(no data).

For now, I just want to check if data is getting inserted properly in Table1, so, I have skipped the foreign key in **Django ORM**, but I am getting the error like "**Null value in column “name” violates not-null constraint** "

Can someone please tell a way to bypass this (or) any new way is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should make your `ForeignKeyField` `nullable` by adding `null=True` to your column definition.